# "The Page Cannot displayed" when uploading file using Internet Explorer. ASP

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

When i upload the file I encounter 'page cannot be displayed'. The size of the file i was uploading is 168 bytes.
I have already tried the code below but still no luck. I'm using I.E. in mobile scanner to upload the file.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="3600" />

<requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1024000000" />
</requestFiltering>
```